# Unable to setup mobx 4 to work with react native

Tags: reactjs, native, mobx

I trying to use mobx 4 with react native, I'm having a few problems with setting up the boiler plate.

I have the following code:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import Store from './store';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  ProductScreen: { screen : ProductScreen }
})

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <Provider store={Store}>
          <AppNavigator />
        </Provider>
      );
  }
}
```

store/index.js

```
import { observable } from 'mobx'
import ProductStore from './ProductStore'

class Store {
    constructor() {
        this.ProductStore= new ProductStore(this)
    }
}
export default Store
```

store/ProductStore.js

```
import { runInAction, extendObservable, action } from "mobx";

export default extendObservable(this, {
  products: [],
  loading: false,

  loadProducts: action(async () => {
    this.loading = true;
    // fetch data from api
    const response = await fetch("https://random.com/api/?results=10");
    const json = await response.json();
    runInAction(() => {
      this.products = json.results;
      this.loading = false;
    });
  })
});
```

ProductsScree:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Alert,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Animated
} from 'react-native';
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";

class ProductsScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          <button onPress={this.props.Store.loadProducts} title="Get Products" />
        </Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default ProductsScreen;
```

I want to be able to trigger the function loadProducts when the button is pressed and to be able to access the data (products, loading vars). Any help with this would be appreciated. Alternatively I will rewrite the code using observable and inject.

Thanks

Comment: I think when `loadProducts()` is called `this` is not the `Product store` have you tried: `this.props.Store.loadProducts.bind(this.props.Store)`?